# DBT: adjust snapshot to handle late arriving data

Tags: sql, snapshot, dbt

I'm new to dbt and I am try to solve a "late arriving data"  situation for a snapshot model;  I was wondering if any of you could help me tackle effectively this issue;

The situation is the following, every once in a while, i read "in full" some data from a source table, which looks like the following:

***SOURCE TABLE  AT T0***

| id | value | id_queue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 |

***SOURCE TABLE  AT T1***

| id | value | id_queue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 25 | 4 |

Changes are recorded into a snapshot table:

```sql
{% snapshot mysnapshottable %}

{{
 config(
 target_schema=env_var('MY_SCHEMA'),
 strategy='check',
 unique_key='ID',
 check_cols=['VALUE', 'ID_QUEUE'],
 )
}} 
select * from {{ ref('source_table') }}

{% endsnapshot %}
```

Now, the problem is this: ID_QUEUE is a MONOTONICALLY INCREASING number that is used to keep things ordered in the case of problem  with the source table writer, for instance, if a piece of data is updated 2 times, it may happens that the first change (the less recent one)  is recorded into the source  AFTER the most recent one. For example, after the two insertions written above, we have the following situation:

| id | value | id_queue | dbt_valid_from | dbt_valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 | T0 | T1 |
| A | 25 | 4 | T1 | NULL |

Now, suppose that for any reason the source table contains, at T2, a previous "change" for the row with ID A

***SOURCE TABLE  AT T2***

| id | value | id_queue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 3 |

The result  of the  snapshot run will be:

| id | value | id_queue | dbt_valid_from | dbt_valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 | T0 | T1 |
| A | 25 | 4 | T1 | T2 |
| A | 20 | 3 | T2 | NULL |

While the desired output should be:

| id | value | id_queue | dbt_valid_from | dbt_valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 | T0 | T1 |
| A | 20 | 3 | T1 | T2 |
| A | 25 | 4 | T2 | NULL |

Is there a smart way/trick to achieve such result?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

A snapshot is just like any other table -- you can build a model off of it and do whatever you want with the data.

You didn't tag your rdbms, but assuming you're on Snowflake or pg/similar, I would use the `rank()` window function on both the `id_queue` and `dbt_valid_from` fields, then join the table to itself to rearrange the dates. That looks like this:

```sql
with
    ranked as (
        select
            *,
            rank() over (
                partition by id order by id_queue asc, dbt_valid_from asc
            ) as id_rank,
            rank() over (
                partition by id order by dbt_valid_from asc, id_queue asc
            ) as ts_rank
        from {{ ref("mysnapshottable") }}
    )
select a.id, a.value, a.id_queue, b.dbt_valid_from, b.dbt_valid_to
from ranked as a
join ranked as b on a.id = b.id and a.id_rank = b.ts_rank
```

This assumes that the combination of `id_queue` and `dbt_valid_from` will be unique for any `id`, which you should write a test for to confirm.